# Node async callback being called for operations complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am trying to use the async library in order to deal with asynchronous functions, and am unable to get the functionality I need.

The basic idea is that I am building a JSON object using multiple calls to a redis database.  I want to only return the JSON object after the redis calls have been completed, so I tried using `async.parallel` but I don't seem to understand it properly.

My callback is called with the empty JSON object and then my console logs within the functions are seen.

Here is my code:

server.js:

```
getHostObject(redis,sess.hostName,function(data) {
  console.log('calledback data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

getHostObject.js

```
  var async = require('async');

  var getHostObject = function(redis, hostName, callback) {

    var hostObject = {
      hostName: hostName,
      pushers: [],
      tracklist: []
    };

    var getSongObject = function(err,song) {
      console.log('song got!');
      hostObject.tracklist.push(song);
    };

    var getSongs = function() {
      redis.lrange(hostName+":songs",0,-1, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {console.log('Error reading songs! '+hostName+'\n'+err);}
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":song:"+data[i], getSongObject);
        }
      });
    };

    var getPusherObject = function(err,pusher) {
      console.log('pusher got!');
      hostObject.pushers.push(pusher);
    };

    var getPushers = function() {
      redis.smembers(hostName+":pushers", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {console.log('Error reading pushers! '+hostName+'\n'+err);}
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":pusher:"+data[i], getPusherObject);
        }
      });
    };

    async.parallel([
      function() {
        getPushers();
      },
      function() {
        getSongs();
      }
    ],callback(hostObject));

  };


  module.exports = getHostObject;
```

console output:

```
calledback data: {"hostName":"47B71","pushers":[],"tracklist":[]}
pusher got!
song got!
```

Comment: How do you know that `redis.hgetall` does complete? You need to tell that to `async.parallel`!

Comment: What do you mean by "tell" async.parallel that hgetall has complete? @Bergi

Comment: Those functions you pass to  `async.parallel` get called with callbacks. You need to use those callbacks!

Comment: problem here too: `,callback(hostObject));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, inside the `getHostObject` function, in the `async.parallel` call, you are passing `callback(hostObject)`. That will be evaluated before the async code is executed, that's why `hostObject` it's empty.

Aside from that, async.parallel needs to know when your individual tasks are completed. That's it, you should call the task callback, following the `error, result` convention. Take a look at [the example](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) in the docs.

You need to change `getPushers` and `getSongs` to use those callbacks, pass the results to the callbacks, and finally compose the `hostObject` in the parallel complete cb.

Im trying to illustrate here based on your code, you will need to modify it to make it work.

```
var getSongs = function(cb) {
      redis.lrange(hostName+":songs",0,-1, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {console.log('Error reading songs! '+hostName+'\n'+err);}
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":song:"+data[i], getSongObject);
        }
        // tracklistData should be the tracklist array, you need to build it first.
        cb(null, tracklistData);
      });
    };

var getPushers = function(cb) {
      redis.smembers(hostName+":pushers", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {console.log('Error reading pushers! '+hostName+'\n'+err);}
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":pusher:"+data[i], getPusherObject);
        }
        // pushersData should be the pushers array, you need to build it first
        cb(null, pushersData);
      });


     };

async.parallel(getSongs, getPushers, function(err, results){
   if(err) // err handling
   callback({
      hostName: hostName,
      pushers: results[1],
      tracklist: results[0]
    });
});
```

When I comment you need to build the array first, I mean that it looks like you might want to use `async.parallel` inside each of those functions as well when you build your array.
Maybe something like

```
var getPushers = function(cb) {
  redis.smembers(hostName+":pushers", function(err, data) {
    var getOperations = [];
    if (err) {console.log('Error reading pushers! '+hostName+'\n'+err);}

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      getOperations.push((function(pusher){
        return function(callback){
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":pusher:"+pusher, callback);
        }
      })(data[i]));
    }

    async.parallel(getOperations, function(err, pushers){
      cb(null, pushers);
    });

  });

 };
```

Comment: Thanks, in transit now but I'll have a look when I get home

Comment: np, it's basically what others outlined in the question comments.

Comment: What is happening on lines 8 & 9 of the second code block where callback is the second argument of `hgetall`? Normally that takes a function with arguments  of `err, data`. How is that data making its way out?

Comment: Don't confuse that `callback` with the one passed into the big `getHostObject`. 
The second arg of `hgetall` takes a fn with `err,data`, and `async.parallel` follows the same convention, so you can just pass it directly. It would be similar than doing:
`return function(callback){
          redis.hgetall(hostName+":pusher:"+pusher, function(err, data){ callback(err, data); });
        }`